# Ubuntu 13.04 -> opencv and qt installation

Tags: qt, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, kdevelop

I'm trying to install opencv (2.4.5) with Qt in my fresh Ubuntu 13.04.

I've downloaded opencv, executed:

```
ccmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ../opencv-2.4.5
```

../opencv-2.4.5 is the folder of the opencv source

and in ccmake I changed the `WITH_QT` variable to YES

than `make` and `sudo make install`

But now if in kdevelop I try to execute my test code (I only call `addText(...)` over an image). I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (The library is compiled without QT support) in fontQt, file...
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion

edit: I had both qt4 and qt5 due to the QtCreator installation.
For a fast solution I removed qt5 and qtcreator and reinstalled opencv.

Now it works, but is there a cmakelist for opecv that enable to use qt5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I should answer my question, anyway:

If you look at the [github repository](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv) of OpenCV, 4 days ago the CMakeList.txt has been updated to support Qt5.

So the solution is to clone the project and install it from source.
I tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at This [Using CMake with Qt 5](http://www.kdab.com/using-cmake-with-qt-5./)

Comment: Oh thank you, I found something similar but not so well explained. I'm not really expert with cmake.

In a couple of days I will try it and see if it works. For now Thanks again.